# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, path, native, libraries

Trying to install JOGL for my Windows Eclipse installation and I'm picking up the error as described in the title.

This is what I did to try and install JOGL:

1. Downloaded jogamp-all-platforms.7z
2. Followed http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL for full installation using native libraries:

   1. Made a new directory called jogl-2.0
   2. Copied the shown .dll files to jogl-2.0\lib
   3. Copied the shown .jar files to jogl-2.0\jar
   4. Copied the shown .zip files to jogl-2.0\src
3. In Eclipse, went to Build Path => Add Libraries... => User Library
4. Created a new user library, set it to system library
5. Add the jars from External JARs
6. Add the dlls by specifying the libraries for each JAR
7. Add javadocs from URLs
8. Add sources from .zips

Yet it still reckons I haven't added the libraries in to complete the installation. I also added jogl-2.0\lib to my %PATH%, but that also did nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst typing this question, I found the solution!

Problem was checking the box for 'system library' in the 'Add Library' dialog. This needs to remain unchecked. If anyone can tell me why, I'll be grateful.

When I unset that, it was fine, but yelled because it couldn't find a couple more JAR files.

I added these JAR files to my jogl-2.0\jar directory and it worked:

```
gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar
jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar
```

I didn't need to do anything more within Eclipse.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you don't make it very clear what the solution to the problem was. Where did you uncheck this 'system library' box?

Comment: In the 'Add Library' menu in Eclipse, sorry.